# Is it possible to remove the .herokuapp part of the url in a rails application running on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, heroku

Hello wonderful world of the stack!

This is my first deployment using Heroku (I am just using their free service at the moment).

I have set up my domain to point to Heroku and renamed my application and everything works fine. the one thing I would like to change however is the format of the final url.

For example, after typing in:

```
www.example.com
```

The page loads and the url changes to:

```
example.herokuapp.com
```

Is there any way that I can change this behaviour so that the url remains the same?

I have tried using the help pages supplied by Heroku and various searches (usually similar searches to this question title) but I am not sure if I am searching for the correct thing as I seem to only get unrelated results.

Thanks in advance for any light you may be able to shed on this matter

Comment: Are you following [their guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)? The redirection sounds strange. Can you provide the link to your website?

Comment: It turns out that this was an issue with ipage rather than an issue with the help pages on heroku. After speaking to them they said it was quite a common problem. I'm now confused as to whether I should delete this question or leave it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound like a problem with your DNS Domain setup rather than heroku. Read about how to configure your domains properly for heroku use [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

It sounds to me as if you are doing some kind of 'web redirection' (custom stuff that each hosting provider offers) with your domain, when you should set CNAME or A Records.

Which provider hosts your domain / where did you 'buy' it?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, it was an IPage issue, after speaking with them on the telephone they said that it was quite a common problem and they had to do something at their end to resolve it. Seems to be working but I'm just waiting for the CNAME to propagate through the DNS lookup until I can confirm